# how to set response header attibute to redirect(302) request

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have a requirement when click on hyper link details should load in the child window.

Following is the code:

```
<a onclick="openChildWindow('http://xx.xxx.xx...');return false;">View details</a>

function openChildWindow(url)
{  
"use strict";

  var child = window.open(url, defaultWindowName);

child.focus();  
}
```

as per the security reasons we need to show response header cache-control attribute value as "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0" for tre requested URL passed in window.open

```
Java side we are resetting the header value to "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0"

Here comes my problem/issue
When I click on hyper link on MS Edge browser in network tab I see two requests of same URL which passed in the window.open one requst response is 200 and another is 302.

for 200 status response header value is setting as expected "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0"
for 302 I see response header cache-control header values is private.

Can someone helps me why in edge browser I see two requests why 302 default value is private. How can I reset this value to "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0" or how can I avoid this 302 request/redirect URL triggered.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reset this value to "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0"

In my opinion, we can't set it header through the window.open method. You could add it from the server side. Please refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections).

> how can I avoid this 302 request/redirect URL triggered.

Please check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections):

302 code the typical use case: The Web page is temporarily not available for reasons that have not been unforeseen. That way, search engines don't update their links.

So, please check the request website, make sure it is available.